# Decrypting string using MCrypt and TripleDES

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have made this code to encrypt the data in a database(It was stored as plain text during to testing purposes):

```
try {
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MAIN", 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM workers WHERE crypt = '0'");
$stmt->execute();
$prepared = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sentinel = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES,'',MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,'');
$key_c = substr(sha1(microtime()),0,24);
$iv = substr(sha1(microtime()),24,8);
mcrypt_generic_init($sentinel, $key_c, $iv);
for($key=0; $key<count($prepared); $key++)
{



    $sort = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['sort']);
    $account = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['account']);
    $bank_name = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['bank_name']);
    $bank_holder = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['bank_holder']);
    $address = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['address']);
    $post_code = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['post_code']);

    $mobile = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['mobile']);
    $phone = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['phone']);

    $kin_name = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['kin_name']);
    $kin_rel = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['kin_relation']);
    $kin_phone = mcrypt_generic($sentinel, $prepared[$key]['kin_phone']);



$stmt = null;
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE workers SET sort = :sort, account = :acc, bank_name = :bank_name, bank_holder = :bank_holder, address = :address, post_code = :post_code, crypt = '1', mobile = :mobile, phone = :phone, kin_name = :kin_name, kin_relation = :kin_rel, kin_phone = :kin_phone WHERE reference = :id");

$stmt->bindParam('sort', base64_encode($sort));
$stmt->bindParam('acc',base64_encode($account));
$stmt->bindParam('bank_name', base64_encode($bank_name));
$stmt->bindParam('bank_holder', base64_encode($bank_holder));
$stmt->bindParam('address', base64_encode($address));
$stmt->bindParam('post_code', base64_encode($post_code));
$stmt->bindParam('mobile', base64_encode($mobile));
$stmt->bindParam('phone', base64_encode($phone));
$stmt->bindParam('kin_name', base64_encode($kin_name));
$stmt->bindParam('kin_rel', base64_encode($kin_rel));
$stmt->bindParam('kin_phone', base64_encode($kin_phone));
$stmt->bindParam('id',$prepared[$key]['reference']);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt=null;

$stmt= $link->prepare('INSERT INTO crypt VALUES (\'\', :id, :key, :iv);');
$stmt->bindParam('id', $prepared[$key]['reference']);
$stmt->bindParam('key', base64_encode($key_c));
$stmt->bindParam('iv',base64_encode($iv));

$stmt->execute();
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {

var_dump($e);
}
```

Everything looks good within the database. Untill I have tried to decrypt the data...:

```
$lnk=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MAIN", 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
$stmt=$lnk->prepare("SELECT * FROM crypt WHERE reference = :ref");
$stmt->bindValue('ref', $result['reference']);
$stmt->execute();
$crypt = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $key_c = base64_decode($crypt['key']);
        $iv = base64_decode($crypt['iv']);

print mcrypt_decrypt ( MCRYPT_3DES , $key_c , base64_decode($result['address']) , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC , $iv)."<br />";
```

Al the data is in place the base64 encodeed keys and vectors everything is perfect, but the decryption of addresses shows an output like this:

> 8×Áê kâäse Avenue

And this problem is with all of the data...

Could anyone explain why did this happend ?

> PHP Version 5.3.15
>   MCrypt Version 2.5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong when you were encoding your IV. If the IV value is incorrect, then (only) the first 8 bytes of the decrypted output will be incorrect, probably `8×Áê kâä`. `se Avenue` is likely to be correct.

Comment: I think the `8x` part is a bit of a fluke, even if it seems unlikely.

Comment: Any idea how to pass this issue or to go around it ?

Comment: Um, yes, try and see what you (the company) did and resolve the correct IV value (in bytes). If you cannot find the IV, you are basically buggered I'm afraid, and left to guessing the first 8 bytes. That might be doable if the postal code is not empty.

Comment: I havemade this in about 3-4 hours and after that started working on decryption and this is the whole code that I have posted ... Do you see something that is going wrong ... ?

Comment: Not directly, I must admit. Maybe you could be confusing references and `id`. Creating a key and IV using microtime is *not* how it should be, it is very likely you are repeating values too.

Comment: Could you give me an example on that (openssl warper library)

Comment: Hmm, cancelled that comment, sorry, I think there is some SMIME encryption in there, but that seems not to be configured for symmetric encryption. Do try to create fully random keys, and make sure that you cannot get to them without sufficient permission.

Comment: Try creating a separate call to mcrypt_generic_init.